# Update UserControl content on the Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There is a MainViewModel in my WPF app which contains a field named ObjectData. And here is my UserControl (nested in another UserControl) which displays this field data.

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ObjectData, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        ...
        <GroupBox ...>
            <Grid>
                ...
                <TextBox
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    AcceptsReturn="True"
                    Text="{Binding ObjectName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is my viewmodel

```
public class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
     ...
     private ObjectData objectData;
     private IOrderData orderData;

     public ObjectData ObjectData
     {
         get => objectData;
         set
         {
             objectData = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ObjectData));
         }
     }

     public RelayCommand Get => new RelayCommand(async o =>
     {
         var id = (int)o;
         await Task.Run(() =>
         {
             var order = orderData.GetById(id);
             ObjectData = order.ObjectData;
         });
     });

     public MainViewModel()
     {
         ObjectData = order.ObjectData;
     }
}
```

So If I initiate ObjectData in MainViewModel constructor it works fine it and fill all the necessary data in my view. But if try to change ObjectData during my app works changes appears viewmodel (I can check with a breakpoint in the Get method) but not in a view.

What did I do wrong?

Update: ObjectData contains inner property ObjectName

Comment: Does objectdata class contain objectname property?

Comment: yes, I've forgot to mention it

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the DataContext Binding is pointless. The Binding is inherently OneWay, and UpdateSourceTrigger only affects TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings. That said, binding the DataContext seems redundant anyway, when you could simply bind the TextBox like `Text="{Binding ObjectData.ObjectName, ...}"`.

Comment: You may also want to check the line `ObjectData = order.ObjectData;` in case it may happen that `order.ObjectData` returns the same ObjectData instance that the view model property already holds. In that case, any property change notification would be ignored. You would have to assign a new instance, or an intermediate null value.

Comment: From the code you showed, can not draw conclusions about the causes of the error.
Give either a more complete code, or (it’s better) a small demo project on GitHub that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this. Reason why this happen because my custom PropertyChangedBase class didn't inherit INotifyPropertyChanged interface.